# Position of the sun: equation of time: what sort of number is this?

Tags: math, sun, astronomy, azimuth

When attempting to calculate the equation of time using the [U.S. Naval Observatory's algorithm](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/SunApprox.php), I end up with the value "300.4580026457396". But what sort of number is this? The value I'm aiming for is 10:23 on 1 Oct 2011 12:00 (+01:00).

Here's how I got it:

```
suns_mean_longitude / 15 - suns_right_ascension
```

Is this the number of days since the start of the year? If so, is this how I'd get the value I'm aiming for?

```
2011-01-01 00:00:00 UTC + suns_mean_longitude / 15 - suns_right_ascension * 60 * 60 * 24
```

This calculation, however, gives me 2011-10-28 10:59:31 UTC, not 2011-10-01 10:23:00 UTC as expected.

So am I doing the right thing, did I mess up some other part of my algorithm?

https://gist.github.com/1278755

Thanks!

--Dwayne

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on Stack Overflow.  Try [here](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Bill the Lizard: I don't understand, there are [tons of similar questions](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/257717/position-of-the-sun-given-time-of-day-and-lat-long) here, yet you didn't ban any of their authors from posting new messages?

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."

Comment: Bill didn't ban you; that's an automatic ban based on percentage of closed and deleted questions (I think - details are not given even to moderators). If you post some good answers, I believe the ban will be automatically removed. Also, for future reference, you can use the normal @username syntax in a comment to contact a moderator who closed a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole part, 300, represents the day of the year. The fractional part is the fraction of the day into that particular day, representing 10:23 AM. Leap years affect this calculation, as well.

Here is a site to help you with [day of calendar calculations](http://daac.gsfc.nasa.gov/julian_calendar.shtml).

Comment: Thank you so much man!! You have no idea how long I've been searching for this answer :)